# Mercedes camper van dimensions

Tags: mercedes-benz, campervan

Would anyone know if this is a full size van? I am curious if it would fit in my garage or not... I have a normal 2 car/stall garage. A minivan would fit no problem...

https://www.motortrend.com/news/2020-mercedes-metris-weekender-price-info/

Most likely rear wheel drive? Diesel option???

Comment: What is the height of a « normal » garage? So many possibilities here, best option is to get yourself a measuring stick.

Comment: I do drive one of these dodge promasters for work, it fits just fine in my garage... Ill have to measure after work.. https://www.ramtrucks.com/ram-promaster-city.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find, the dimensons of the standard van upon which this vehicle is based are [here](https://www.autoblog.com/buy/2019-Mercedes_Benz-Metris-Base__Metris_Passenger_Van/specs/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAM6ZrXkqAoCS8vbJVufts_pxmcGfNbUBQNo1iJmzwEJD0uLL_JRNEdUsNf7b-WaGrbox5J0Tfhp07NoK1UqBgad_oiRSMCnnBTPpbd5DCE3SuegvLes7Z2BprDTj_eeJRpkV26f2PnZUB1bTSQ6RYX58Pv1TROhwX3GtN-3GwXtX)

I'd assume that the overall length and width of the camper will be the same and the poptop roof, when folded, may add a few inches to the eight.

Measure your own garage and note the measurements (height of open door rather than height to ceiling) and if it's too small assume it won't fit.  If it isn't too small, don't assume it will be instead talk directly to Mercedes and give them your garage measurements as they'll be able to verify it for you.

Comment: Looks like rear wheel drive. I see 2.0 straight 4 cylinder.. Any idea if a diesel option exists?

Comment: I know a SWB version of this vehicle is sold in the UK with a diesel option so it wouldn’t surprise me if a diesel version of the weekender were available but there is a chance they may chose to go with petrol only for the smoothness?